# laravel unit test for import csv file using maatwebsite/excel

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, import, maatwebsite-excel

I am trying to write unit tests for my import service that implemented using maatwebsite/excel package. but I cant make it work it always fails! I already read the package doumentaion about test but its not clear to me.

here is my controller method :

```
public function store(ImportEmployeeRequest $request)
{
    try {
        EmployeeFacade::importEmployees($request->file('file'));
        return response()->json('Your file is importing. The rows have errors will logged on    import_failed channel!', Response::HTTP_OK);
    } catch (\Throwable $throwable) {
        throw new ImportFailedException('File import failed.', Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, $throwable);
    }
}
```

Here is the service:

```php
class EmployeeService
{
    public function __construct(protected EmployeeRepositoryInterface $employeeRepository)
    { }

    public function importEmployees($file)
    {
        $filePath = $this->uploadFile($file);
        return ProcessEmployeeImportJob::dispatch(Storage::disk('public')->path($filePath));
    }

    private function uploadFile($file)
    {
        $file_name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $path = 'employee/excel';
        $filePath = Storage::disk('public')->putFileAs(
            $path,
            $file,
            $file_name
        );
        return $filePath;
    }
}
```

here is the importJob:

```
public function handle(): void
{
    $import = new EmployeesImport();
    $import->import($this->file);
    if($import->failures()->isNotEmpty())
    {
        foreach ($import->failures() as $failure) {
            Log::info($failure->row());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the import class:

```
public function model(array $row)
{
    try {
        return new Employee([
            'employee_id' => $row['emp_id'],
            'username' => $row['user_name'],
            'name_prefix' => $row['name_prefix'],
            'first_name' => $row['first_name'],
            'middle_initial' => $row['middle_initial'],
            'last_name' => $row['last_name'],
            'gender' => $row['gender'],
            'email' => $row['e_mail'],
            'date_of_birth' => Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $row['date_of_birth'])->format('Y-m-d'),
            'time_of_birth' =>  Carbon::createFromFormat('h:i:s A', $row['time_of_birth'])->format('H:i:s'),
            'age_in_years' => $row['age_in_yrs'],
            'date_of_joining' => Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $row['date_of_joining'])->format('Y-m-d'),
            'age_in_company' => $row['age_in_company_years'],
            'phone_no' => $row['phone_no'],
            'place_name' => $row['place_name'],
            'country' => $row['county'],
            'city' => $row['city'],
            'zip' => $row['zip'],
            'region' => $row['region'],
        ]);
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        // Handle the exception (log it or perform any other action)
        return null; // Return null so this row is skipped
    }
}

public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'emp_id' => ['required', 'numeric','unique:employees,employee_id'],
        'user_name' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:50','unique:employees,username'],
        'name_prefix' => ['required', 'string', 'min:1', 'max:20'],
        'first_name' => ['required', 'string', 'min:1', 'max:50'],
        'middle_initial' => ['required', 'string', 'min:1', 'max:10'],
        'last_name' => ['required', 'string', 'min:1', 'max:50'],
        'gender' => ['required', 'string', "in:M,F"],
        'e_mail' => ['required', 'email', 'min:4', 'max:150'],
        'date_of_birth' => ['required', 'string','regex:/^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/\d{4}$/'],
        'time_of_birth' => ['required', 'string', 'regex:/^((0?[1-9]|1[0-2]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]) (AM|PM))$/'] ,
        'age_in_yrs' => ['required', 'numeric'],
        'date_of_joining' => ['required', 'string','regex:/^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/\d{4}$/'],
        'age_in_company_years' => ['required', 'numeric'],
        'phone_no' => ['required', 'string','regex:/^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/'],
        'place_name' => ['required', 'string', 'min:1', 'max:50'],
        'county' => ['required', 'string', 'min:1', 'max:50'],
        'city' => ['required', 'string', 'min:1', 'max:50'],
        'zip' => ['required','regex:/\b\d{4,5}\b/'],
        'region' => ['required', 'string', 'min:1', 'max:50'],
    ];
}

public function chunkSize(): int
{
    return 1000;
}

public function batchSize(): int
{
    return 1000;
}

public function onFailure(Failure ...$failures)
{
    foreach ($failures as $failure){
        Log::channel('import_failed')->error($failure->row());
        Log::channel('import_failed')->error($failure->attribute());
        Log::channel('import_failed')->error($failure->errors());
        Log::channel('import_failed')->error($failure->values());
    }
}
```

and here is the importTest :

```
public function test_employees_can_be_imported()
{
    Excel::fake();
    $this->get('/employee/import/csv');
    // $import = new EmployeesImport();
    // $import->import('employee/excel/import.csv');

    Excel::assertQueued('employee/excel/import.csv', 'public');

    Excel::assertQueued('employee/excel/import.csv', 'public', function(EmployeesImport $import) {
        return true;
    });

    // When passing the callback as 2nd param, the disk will be the default disk.
    Excel::assertQueued('employee/excel/import.csv', function(EmployeesImport $import) {
        return true;
    });
}
```

the test always fails and errors:

```
 FAILED  Tests\Unit\EmployeeImportTest > employees can be imported                                                                                                                                        
  import.csv is not stored on disk public
Failed asserting that an array has the key 'import.csv'.
```

Any suggestion or clue to lead me write couple up unit tests for the import process will be appreciated. Thank you all :)

Comment: I have never used this package, but I am reading the documentation and you are manually using a queue job, when the documentation mentions you to use `Excel::queueImport(new UsersImport, 'users.xlsx');` or similar, you are literally handling the import yourself, that may be why your `assertQueued` is not working at all... Check the [documentation](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/queued.html#explicit-queued-imports) again please